# Assigning ID's to table column and adding a click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to find out if all my days in the calendar have an ID since I was planning to access documents on that day in my database. My problem is that there is only one ID being assigned to the table column and clicking on it after a number of tries increases the number of alert messages I am getting...just what am I missing/doing wrong?

Php calendar portion for days

```
    $list_day = 1;
while($list_day <= $days_in_month){
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
        /* add in the day number */
        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number" id = "day'.$list_day.'" onclick = displayDocuments()>'.$list_day.'</div>';

        /** QUERY THE DATABASE FOR AN ENTRY FOR THIS DAY !!  IF MATCHES FOUND, PRINT THEM !! **/
        $calendar.= str_repeat('<p> </p>',2);

    $calendar.= '</td>';
    if($running_day == 6){
        $calendar.= '</tr>';
        if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month){
            $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
        }
        $running_day = -1;
        $days_in_this_week = 0;
    }
    $days_in_this_week++;
    $running_day++;
    $day_counter++;
    $list_day++;
}
```

Javascript for checking whether I have other ID's being assigned

```
function displayDocuments(){
    $('#day1').click(function(){
        alert('day 1!');
        });
    $('#day2').click(function(){
        alert('day 2!');
        });
}
```

Comment: How about you quote the value of id attribute in your html and try again with that?

Comment: wow...didn't adding quotes there would fix that since I thought I only need quotes on names separated by spaces...thanks

Comment: though I am wondering why the alert message still repeats more than once

Comment: Its repeating more than once because once you click on a day, it starts function `displayDocuments()`, this function has 2 alerts in it. `day 1!` and `day 2!`.

Comment: It repeats because the click() function assigns a click LISTENER.  Check out the documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: @DaanHeskes it doesn't repeat day 1! and day 2!...just day 1! if I click on the first day and it repeats numerous times

Comment: Because every time you run `displayDocuments()` you add a new click Listener to `#day1` and `#day2`. If you click on these, they will run the two alerts and run the function `displayDocuments()` (`onclick='displayDocuments()'` in your HTML), which AGAIN adds a Listener to `#day1` and `#day2` and it again runs the function `displayDocuments()` which AGAIN gives them an extra listener and so on and so forth.

Comment: I see...it seems my understanding is wrong since I thought it went like...If(#day1 is clicked) then alert day 1!

Comment: That could be done, you just have to remove the HTML `onclick='displayDocuments()'` and remove the `function displayDocuments()` so you now only have the day1 click and day2 click listeners. I don't suggest you to write this code for every day, but use my code with the `.each` function on the class `day-number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking this can be done by looping to the classes that every day has, in your example: `day-number`. Then alerting the id to see wether it exists or not.

**HTML:**

```
$calendar.= '<div class="day-number" id="day'.$list_day.'">'.$list_day.'</div>';
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".day-number").each(function() {
        var currentid = $(this).attr("id");
        alert(currentid);
    });
});
```

**Possible outputs:**

- **day1** - day1 exists
- **day2** - day2 exists

If it alerts day1, day2, etc. you know that the ID is set on the particular day, if it doesn't alert it; you know it isn't set.

Because you're using PHP I'm not able to show you on a JSFiddle, but I hope this helps you check wether every day has an ID.

Comment: I didn't know about the each function...that is handy. Though for some reason the $(this).id returns undefined whenever I tried it hence why I just specified the ID's

Comment: Ah because your PHP isn't right, let me change my answer.

Comment: You didn't set the ID right, `id = day'.$list_day.'` is the same as id=day1, which isn't quoted out. Changed it to: `id="day'.$list_day.'"` which is the same as id="day1".

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to update question...I updated it and it's still repeating

Comment: If you change your HTML with the one that's written in my answer now, does it still output an undefined ID, or does it work?

Comment: it's giving out the right number of alerts given the number of days in my calendar but yes it still states undefined in the alert message

Comment: My bad, ofcourse the ID is `undefined` as I wrote `$(this).id` which is incorrect. It should be replaced by `$(this).attr("id");`, as you see in my answer now. Could you try again with this code? :)

Comment: It displays properly now thanks... An off-topic question though: is it supposed to display every time I refresh/open the page? It doesn't seem to be that way if you write them one by one

Comment: Glad I helped you :) - It's doing that because I put the loop in the `$(document).ready(function)`, which runs when the document is fully loaded. You could put the loop in every function.

Comment: thanks for the answers...I'm relatively new to javascript so I hope I'm not bothering too much